# "Sides remain orbiting Saturn"

Tags: meaning, idioms

This is idiom of laughing hard, i'm right? Or there any other meaning?

It was said after one funny situation.

Comment: What was the context?  Who said this? Did they say it to you?

Comment: Whole sentence - Sides remain orbiting Saturn for the rest of the encounter. It's just description of reaction, and not say to anyone in particular.

Comment: So the source is reddit? 
 Please link to the source when one exists https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDGreentext/comments/6fefry/a_wizards_only_weakness/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard it before, however, google returns a single result for [a post on a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DnDGreentext/comments/6fefry/a_wizards_only_weakness/) which does appear to mean "we continued to laugh hard".

There is an idiom "split one's sides laughing" which means "to laugh very hard".  My guess is that the reddit result is a bit of hyperbole, made up by *ImpulsiveZombie* for the sake of the reddit post, not a well-known idiom.

Comment: Well, it was my guess too, just want to be sure.